# Передача переменной JavaScript в PayPal счет

Tags: php, javascript, paypal

[Есть такой сайт.](http://bestautoparts.eu/3aa920880-3aa920-880/instrument-cluster/vw/)
Стоимость детали рассчитывается с помощью функции:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".txt1", ".txt2").each(function() {
            $(this).load(function(){
                calculateSum1();
            });
        });

    });
    function calculateSum1() {
        var sum = 0;
        $(".txt1").each(function() {
            if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
        });
        $("#sum1").html(sum.toFixed(2));
<body onLoad="calculateSum1();>
</script>
```

И передается в `<span id="sum1">0</span>`

И передается через `paypal.php`:

```
<input name="amount" type="hidden" value="<?php echo intval('<span id="sum1">0</span>'); ?>" />
```

Но [PayPal](https://www.paypal.com/ua/home) не подхватывает значение переменной.

Видимо переменная рассчитывается на стороне клиента.

Как правильно передать переменную через форму `paypal.php` ?

Comment: Не понятно зачем вы значение расчета с разу не запихиваете в `value`?